# Android get content length return -1 in downloading file

Tags: android

I have this piece of code which is going to download some file ,

```
URL url = new URL("the url");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
```

but the getContentLength method returns -1 but the file is downloadable in any kind of internet browser .

Is this about MIME types of IIS or something ?

-------- ANSWER -------------
I've added a .map MIME Type ( same as zip files "application/x-zip-compressed") to IIS . That was solved the problem .

Comment: @Selvin - This code is inside of an AsyncTask and the error you mentioned is never happening ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a .map MIME Type ( same as zip files "application/x-zip-compressed") to IIS .
That was solved the problem .

Answer (score 1):

well it Returns the content length in bytes specified by the response header field content-length but it will return -1 if this field is not set.

Are you checking that you have definitely connected?

Answer (score 0):

Check the rest of the http headers, I would guess that the file is being streamed using chunked-encoding which means there will be no content length available.

I would suggest opening the inputstream for the connection and reading from it until it returns -1 for the end of the stream

Comment: I am sure my class works fine for downloading but for a given type (.map) it is returning -1 (most times) or wrong number

Answer (score 0):

it could be because the server is not setting content-length in the response header

Comment: I think so, how could I set it in IIS ?